# Aggregation on Hierarchy Data types

Tags: t-sql, hierarchy, aggregation

I've been reading about the Hierarchy data type in MS SQL2012.  I'm trying to store an organisation data structure with values at each level.  I'm wondering how do you aggregate data that is associated to a Hierarchy data column.

for instance say I want to sum up everything to 3 levels from the top of the hierarchy, what would I use to do that.  What I use a group by or a roll-up or is there some new function I could use on the hierarchy data type.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up everything up to 3 levels it looks like you could use GetLevel as per this link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/3b4f7dae-65b5-4d8d-8641-87aba9aa692d
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb677197(v=sql.100).aspx

```
SELECT SUM(z)
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeOrg
WHERE OrgNode.GetLevel() BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Comment: select sum(pop)
from [dbo].[Population]
where [Hindx].GetLevel()

Comment: Not sure what you're saying - If you post your DDL I could come up with a query more aligned to your tables rather than posting generic ones. Note the condition `where [Hindx].GetLevel()` is not valid - you need an expression that evaluates to a boolean, not a number.